# Do we need to wrap return value into promise using async/await?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Just wanted to understand correct approach using async/await when we return the value in async functions. what would be correct way to write code for async functions and return the value with promise ?

main.ts

```
private async customerResponse(data: any): Promise < any > {

    const custObject: any = data;

    Promise.resolve(custObject);
    Or 
    return custObject;


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about typescript, but in JavaScript the `async` keyword already ensures that any immediately returned values are wrapped in a resolved Promise.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't take my word for it (especially since I provided a [working link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=async%20function%20foo()%3A%20Promise%3CString%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo().then(console.log)%3B)) on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045609/async-function-must-be-global-promiset-type)?

Comment: example you provided was complicated to understand so i asked another question related to that issue.

Comment: @hussain It literally is just a async function that returns a string which `then` is printed to the console. I even added the return type annotation to show that the types check. How could I have made it simpler?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An `async` function returns a promise. Moreover, you only need to use `async` if you need the `await` keyword. If you're not using `await`, don't use `async`.

The return value of an `async` function is effectively unwrapped to a single level when using `Promise.resolve` (I think this is part of `Promise.resolve` functionality), so there is no difference between returning `Promise.resolve(value)` or just returning `value` (or `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve(value))` for that matter). That said, you should simply return the desired return value from `async` functions and not worry about doing any additional wrapping.